# Are Restrictions and Projections deprecated from Hibernate 5.2 onwards?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria, hibernate-5.x, jpa-criteria

Are [Restrictions](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html) and [Projections](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Projections.html) deprecate from Hibernate 5.2 onwards?
If so what are the JPA Criteria API equivalents.

Other Related Q's -

1. Does the Hibernate Criteria Extensions API (which supports deprecated api have the Restriction an Projections as part of them still. If they do. Could you share the api doc)
2. Is there some place where i can find what all api's/classes/methods are deprecated. I have gone through [legacy-criteria](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#appendix-legacy-criteria) , but it does not clearly say what all things are deprecated. It would have been nice if they listed them out explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing an answer for Hibernate 5.6.x:

- `Restrictions` is *not* marked deprecated. Check the corresponding [JavaDoc](https://javadoc.io/static/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.6.10.Final/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html).
- `Projections`, likewise, is also *not* marked deprecated, see related [JavaDoc](https://javadoc.io/static/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.6.10.Final/org/hibernate/criterion/Projections.html).

As it stands now, both classes are *not* deprecated for version 5.6.x. Nevertheless, Hibernate’s Criteria API is deprecated as such, and ongoing development (version 6+) will focus on the JPA Criteria API.

However, it seems [open for debate](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/deprecation-of-hibernate-criteria-and-how-we-can-still-prevent-it/788) if the JPA community will move forward towards the vendor-agnostic `CriteriaBuilder`.

Check the [deprecation list](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.6.10.Final/deprecated-list.html) of Hibernate‘s JavaDoc for an overview and further details.

Comment: with out a second though accepting.. superb.

Comment: after the answer.. i see the Q makes good sense.. would you mind upvoting if you like it.

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate 6 removed the legacy Hibernate Criteria API which was deprecated in 5.2 and with it, the two classes you asked for.
Essentially, everything related to the legacy Criteria API (package and sub-packages of `org.hibernate.criterion`) is deprecated and shouldn't be used if you want to be able to easily migrate to 6.0+

Comment: can the depreciated packages be used from hibernate criteria extensions. I am not sure what the extension will include. Can you comment on this. +1

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `hibernate criteria extensions`, but you can of course still use all of this even though it is deprecated. Deprecation is just a warning that things might go away, and in fact, the whole criterion package went away in 6.0, so you just have to keep in mind that your code won't work with 6.0+ anymore.

Comment: sorry i meant jpa extentions - from the doc -> `Hibernate-specific criteria features will be ported as extensions to the JPA`. The above comment answers. tx.

Comment: With Hibernate 6.0+ you can use certain subclasses of JPA Criteria interfaces which are Hibernate specific extension. These extensions aim to be a replacement for features offered in the legacy Criteria API. So if you want to switch to 6.0+ you can use these APIs